# A quantity based on two vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

Suppose there are two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have stumbled across the following quantity:
$$
\sum_{i \neq j} (\alpha x_i - \beta y_i)(\alpha x_j - \beta y_j),
$$
where $\alpha, \beta$ are positive and satisfy $\alpha+ \beta=1$.

The above quantity can also be written as
$$
\sum_{i \neq j}\left( \alpha^2 x_i x_j + \beta^2 y_i y_j - \alpha \beta (x_i y_j + x_j y_i) \right).
$$

Are there any geometric interpretations for this quantity or any of the subparts in the last representation?

Comment: What interesting properties, if any, have you found?